# Is it possible to secure Docker Container with alternative bash?

Tags: docker, security

Is there any quick/dirty way to secure docker images to prevent to drop in shell ? is it possible way to remove or rename /bin/bash to  another name and put /bin/bash a honeypot ?

Best

Comment: Remember that anyone who can run any `docker` command can trivially get unrestricted root-level access on the system.  They can browse the files in `/var/lib/docker` if they choose, or bind-mount a BusyBox binary into a container if they're motivated.  You could try this, but it will interfere with any script trying to use the "real" bash as an interpreter, and it doesn't actually add any security.

Comment: just looking quick  and dirty solution. misdirection and using honeypot may be.